# How to access object inside object in Laravel Blade file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some data like below and I am trying to get an object inside the object in Laravel blade file usually it's supposed to work but here in the blade file in Laravel not working can you help me?

```php
{
  "id": 2,
  "branch_id": 1,
  "counselor_id": 3,
  "universities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lead_id": 2,
      "institute": 1,
      "course": {
        "id": 3,
        "institute_id": 1,
        "course_category_id": 4,
        "course_level_id": 1,
        "course_name": "BSc (Hons) Counselling",
        "course_duration": "3",
        "course_intake": "January, September",
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-06-10T06:40:45.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-06-10T06:40:45.000000Z",
        "institute": {
          "id": 1,
          "represent_country_id": 1,
          "institute_name": "University Name Here",
          "campus_name": "London",
          "active": 1,
          "created_at": "2021-06-10T06:41:52.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-06-10T06:41:52.000000Z"
        }
      },
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "lead_id": 2,
      "institute": 2,
      "course": {
        "id": 13,
        "institute_id": 2,
        "course_category_id": 10,
        "course_level_id": 1,
        "course_name": "BSc (Hons) Business and Events Management",
        "course_duration": "3",
        "course_intake": "January, May & September",
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-06-10T06:40:45.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-06-10T06:40:45.000000Z",
        "institute": {
          "id": 2,
          "represent_country_id": 1,
          "institute_name": "University Name Here",
          "campus_name": "London",
          "active": 1,
          "created_at": "2021-06-10T06:41:52.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-06-10T06:41:52.000000Z"
        }
      },
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  ]
}
```

blade.php

```php
<div class="course-interest">
       <ul>
          @foreach ($applicant_infos['universities'] as $university)
             <li>{{ $university['course']['course_name'] }}</li>
          @endforeach
       </ul>
</div>
```

it's not working. can anyone help me to how to access object inside object in laravel blade ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access like below if you are passing model object

```
 @foreach ($applicant_infos->universities as $university)
             <li>{{ $university->course->course_name }}</li>
          @endforeach
```

**Updated.**

you have to pass data to markdown like below

```
 return $this->markdown('emails.application_email',['app_body'=>$this->app_body,'applicant_infos'=>$this->applicant_infos]);
```

Comment: `<li>{{ $university->course->course_name }}</li>` It's not working I have tried many times in this way

Comment: pelase show how you passing data in controller

Comment: It's actually mailable class

Comment: what erorr you are getting now

Comment: try once $university->course['course_name ']

Comment: let me try once

Comment: thee issue is you have to pass data to markdown

Comment: return $this->markdown('mail.user_registration',['data'=> $this->data,'user'=>$this->user]);

Comment: i have updated answer. if you pass data in markdown then you access like object

Comment: Actually getting error after passing markdown data

http://prntscr.com/15558ne

Comment: show your markdown template code in question.dont share screenshot

Comment: looks good once you try dd($this->applicant_infos]);) before markdown.also try once

Answer (score 0):

First check if `$university->course` is not empty:

```
{{ $university->course ? $university->course->course_name : 'Course Not Found' }}
```